# django-rest-framework-simplejwt disable refresh

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt, token

Is there a way to disable refresh token?

Take away refresh field from the response.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @alamshafi2263. I think you give the perfect direction.

Don't know why, I still git the `refresh` item from server response, not Django Shell. (also see the debug variables in photo).
So I just simply `data.pop('refresh', None)` it out, then problem solved.

Thank you for your time and code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**The Easy Way**

Write a view of your own extending the `TokenObtainPairView` and override the `post` method.

```py
# in your views.py

from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView


class MyTokenView(TokenObtainPairView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        except TokenError as e:
            raise InvalidToken(e.args[0])
        serializer.validated_data.pop('refresh', None)
        return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

# in your urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/token/', MyTokenView.as_view()),
]
```

**The Complicated but Nicer Way**

You need to create a serializer extending `TokenObtainSerializer` and then define a Custom View as above. This time put your new serializer as the serializer_class of this view and forget about the post method.

```py
# in your serializers.py
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

class MyTokenObtainSerializer(TokenObtainSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        return RefreshToken.for_user(user)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)

        refresh = self.get_token(self.user)

        data['access'] = str(refresh.access_token)

        return data


# in your views.py
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

from .serializers import MyTokenObtainSerializer

class MyTokenView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainSerializer

# in your urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/token/', MyTokenView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the nicer way, but the problem remains. It seems skipping the `data['refresh']` in `validate()` doesn't work. It return refresh&access, even I remove the `data['access'] = ...` .  simplejwt=4.3.0.

Comment: Hey, I have tried it and it only returns access token in the `serializer.validated_data`. You may check it by running this script in your django shell - https://gist.github.com/shafi2263/6bb24d5f17acda858ecc61dcec5a6819

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the user.tokens() dictionary

```
user.tokens()['access']
user.tokens()['refresh]
```

And pass them to "tokens" key while in Response